# Arquillian Garphene, page loaded but unable to launch javascript

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Arquillian Graphene with Selenium 2.

The trouble is coming from the `Graphene.guardNoRequest();` method. 
The error thrown is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Can't execute JavaScript before a page has been loaded!

Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_43'
```

I've also tried to get elements to assert that they exist, i've catched the page source and everything seems to be ok. I've tried to put a wait like

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("selector here")));
```

Someone has/had the same struggle?

---

***UPDATE : Problem solved***

**I've solved this problem, but i need some time to make a clear explain about what happens and what's my solution**

Comment: How much time will you take to clarify about what happened and what was your solution :D ...please share your solution

Comment: @Coder, I don't have the solution, because i'm not working anymore for the same company and the code stayed with this company.. i can give a try...